# Warning C4047 : 'int **' differs in level of indirection from 'int[2][4]'

Tags: c, parameters, indirection

I'm getting this warning and scratching my head about why. I found many thread here that address this warning in VS 2017 compiler, but not this particular combination: why isn't int** the same level of indirection as int[X][Y]?

Here's a distilled down example that generates the warning:

```
void testfunc(int ** input, int ** output) {

  /*
  * Do something
  */

}


int main()
{


  int   firstvar[2][4];
  int   secondvar[2][4];

  testfunc(firstvar, secondvar);

}
```

I get:

> testcode.c(46): warning C4047: 'function': 'int **' differs in levels of indirection from 'int [2][4]'

Any thoughts on why this would be or how to fix it much appreciated.

Comment: `int**` is *not* a 2D array. You cannot access 2D array elements using such a pointer.

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers.  Arrays *decay* into pointers, but that doesn't mean that a 2D array can decay into a pointer-to-pointer. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void testfunc(int input[][4], int output[][4])
```

would be a better way to pass this. Please note int ** seems to indicate it is an array of int *, which it is not.

```
void onedimension_testfunc(int *odinput, int *odoutput)
{
     ...
}

int main ()
{
      int odfirst[4], odsecond[4];
      onedimention_testfunc(odfirst, odsecond);
}
```

In one dimension the above code works fine. Thats because odinput/odoutput in the above code points to an integer array. But not for multiple dimensions.

Comment: And it worth noting that the actual type passed would be `int (*input)[4]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I didn't pass it as int[][4], though, is that the actual dimensions will be variable. I think I will need to redesign this as a single dimension structure and pass in also the magnitude of the first dimension, so that it can be accessed as rowsize*r +c

Comment: You don't have to use one-dimensional arrays if your data is two dimensional. Just use variable sized 2d-arrays as parameters like this: `void testfunc(size_t n, size_t m, int input[n][m], int output[n][m])` And call it like this: `testfunc(2, 4, firstvar, secondvar);`